# JPEG to Video stream

Tags: image, video, stream, jpeg

We are getting images from a third party and want to have a software that compresses the images and streams them. We are wondering if anyone knows of any `software/api` that does this.

I saw these online but unsure if it what I want.

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/
http://splicer.codeplex.com/

Again we are getting images from a third party, we want to stream these images as a video feed on a website (we dont want to display them as image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[avifile](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library) wrapper should be one of the best options.